# How to delete a cosmosDB document that ends with blank space?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

Somehow we have managed to insert a document where the id ends with a space, now this document fails to load in portal and in any db tool I have tried with the following error

```
Resource Id cannot end with space
```

How can I delete this document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a valid workaround using the .NET SDK: https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/sql/troubleshoot-not-found#invalid-character-in-an-item-id